# Add to cart with data from a URL (post) using the GET method in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using a shortcode to show a small list of products in any post, what I want is that in some way when adding the cart I get data from the post where I added the cart, something like this:

http://example.com/cart/?add-to-cart=10&post_title=10_best_flowers

And that data appears in the cart and checkout area

Any idea how to do it? I am open to any option

Comment: **And that data appears in the cart and checkout area** This part is complex, you'll have to store this data in session during add to cart and the store as cart item meta then remove the data from the session. If you're interested to develop it then you can find tutorials on [How to Add Custom Data to WooCommerce Order](https://wisdmlabs.com/blog/add-custom-data-woocommerce-order/)

Comment: Note: This question is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73832763/get-the-post-id-or-title-from-where-a-woocommerce-product-was-added

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_url` hook with some check that your inside the shortcode.

You can set some global variable inside the start of the shortcode like that.

```
$GLOBALS['custom-shortcode'] = true;
```

...

and before the end of the shortcode, clear that check.

```
unset( $GLOBALS['custom-shortcode'] );
```

then use `woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_url` to adjust the add to cart link.

```
add_filter(
   'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_url',
   function( $add_to_cart_url ) {
          $is_target_shortcode = ! empty( $GLOBALS['custom-shortcode'] );
          if ( $is_target_shortcode ) {
            $add_to_cart_url = add_query_arg(
               array(
                  'post_title' => get_the_title(),
               ),
               $add_to_cart_url
            );
          }
       return $add_to_cart_url;
  },
  1000,
  1
);
```